# How are thread blocks are assigned to multiprocessors on NVIDIA GPUs?

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia

Let's say I have 8 thread blocks that need to be executed, and 8 SMs(Streaming Multiprocessor) on my GPU, and 8 thread blocks can fit into a single SM. I want to know how thread blocks are assigned to SMs. Will all of the thread blocks be assigned to a single SM, and the other 7 are empty? or will each thread block be assigned to a separate SM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This information is basically unspecified by CUDA.  There is no description of rules that the block scheduler will follow.

Empirically, it's not difficult to show that the CUDA block scheduler will deposit blocks on empty SMs preferentially, before depositing blocks on SMs that have one or more blocks already resident.

The reasons for this preferential behavior are clear.  This is the way to take best advantage of the GPUs resources distributed across the device; it leads to highest performance across a range of grid sizes, for any given GPU.